# Unable to Display JSON Data Received on HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

So ive managed to get my script to retrieve some JSON data through $http.get and i get my JSON data in Object Form. However, im not able to use the values in the array.

[image: JSON in Web Console]

Here is my AppCtrl portion (AngularJS)

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$http) {


$scope.data = [];
$scope.submit = function() {

var link = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/api.asp';
$http.get(link).then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
    console.log($scope.data);
});
};
});
```

Here is the HTML bit

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
      <input class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit To Server">
    </form>
    <div class="card">
        <li ng-repeat="userdata in data">
          Username : {{userdata.username}}
          Age : {{userdata.age}}
        </li>
    </div>
```

Eventhough ive retrieved the json data, im unable to retrieve it. Im guessing it has something to do with me not calling it right ? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE : The console.log($scope.data) returns

> "0     925121   log      [object Object]"

Ive attempted to run JSON.stringify on the response.data , i now get a different console.Log result , and a new error .

The console.log returned the JSON info as

> {"data":[{"ID":1,"age":"24","username":"hidir"},{"ID":2,"age":"51","username":"ibrahim"}]}

And the error is the following which suggest that i have duplicate values in the array which doesnt look like it does.  :

```
"Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: userdata in data, Duplicate key: string:a, Duplicate value: a
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=userdata%20in%20data&p1=string%3Aa&p2=a
```

"

Comment: Can you provide the output of console.log($scope.data);, which you are getting in browser console.

Comment: Yeah, like Deepesh, I suspect data isn’t an array as you are expecting.

Comment: In code <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" ng-model="data.username">, why are you binding value of username to the array data?

Comment: $scope.data = []; why this line required here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.name = null;
    $scope.submit = function() {
        var link = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/api.asp';
        $http.get(link).then(function(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
            if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                //$digest or $apply
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: With the added $scope.$apply(); , im getting another error "$digest already in progress" and no longer get json data.

Comment: Hey Abhi, the new one no longer gives error but it did not change anything.

Comment: Actually not sure but I have written your complete code in plunkr and ran it, It's working. Can you match the complete process?

https://plnkr.co/edit/HoPY4kHO3cYtRQ617dfM?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much for the Plunkr code. I switched the link variable to that of mine. And the Plunkr stopped working . Now i know there is something wrong with the format of my JSON. Will check out it and update, thank you once again

Comment: Ok you can update me what happens. May be it will add some more good knowledge to me :)

Comment: Ive posted the solution ive found. Your code was very useful. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use success function after $http call like below

```
$http.get(link).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
};
```

Comment: this isn't an answer. She is already getting json data. Please check the question again.

Answer (score 0):

try to use JSON.stringify(response.data);

Comment: This is an interesting option. Ive updated my question with an error i got from doing this .

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$http({
  url : link,
  method : "GET",
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'applcation/json'
     }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.data = angular.fromJson(response.data);
    console.log($scope.data);
});
```

Comment: Did not work as the JSON data is already an object. So this gave the same consolelog result.

Comment: Hey Devidas, this gave me 2 json data, however i still face the same problem. The second one consist of status,headers,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Abhinav 's code, I found out that the problem was with my JSON format. I hope someone can explain it here better for future references as I'm not well versed enough to explain in detail.

*First JSON Format that didn't work

```
{"data":[{"ID":1,"age":"24","username":"hidir"},{"ID":2,"age":"51","username":"ibrahim"}]}
```

For the above code, it will only work if I call it with `{{userdata[0].username}}`. Using the `ng-repeat` with this format will fail.

Array Form (working for Ionic)

```
[{"ID":1,"age":"24","username":"hidir"},{"ID":2,"age":"51","username":"ibrahim"}]
```

`ng-repeat` works well with the second format.

Comment: Actually earlier you were getting one object from api. That objecting was having array of user details. So if you needed to use those items then that "data" object was having array so I think either you could use `$scope.data = response.data.data[0]` or the second array is fine for sure. 
One more thing is if you use $http.get().success(function(response) { }) then you will get directly the data which was sent by api i.e. $scope.data = response. But if you use $http.get().then(function(response) { }) then you will get the same data using `data` property i.e. $scope.data =  response.data.